# TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null after screen resize when using React.createRef

Tags: reactjs, ref, react-component

I am trying to attach a reference to each `StyledSlide` styled component below and then measure the `offsetHeight` of each to determine which slide is the tallest.

Below I am using `React.createRef`. This works almost fine for the initial render, but when I resize the browser I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null

If I perform a `console.log(this.refArray)` I can still see each reference and find the `offsetHeight` in the console.

What I am trying to do is on resize to re-calculate the tallest slide.

Below is a Pseudo example of the main parts that are relevant:

```js
class CarouselComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.refArray = [];
  }

  handleResize = () => {
    let highestSlide = 0;

    this.refArray.forEach(ref => {
      if (highestSlide < ref.current.offsetHeight) {
        highestSlide = ref.current.offsetHeight;
      }
    });
    console.log(`highest slide: ${highestSlide}`);
    console.log(this.refArray);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  getAllSlides = () => {
    const { collectionOfSlides } = this.props;

    return collectionOfSlides.map((component, index) => {
      const slideHeightRef = React.createRef();
      this.refArray.push(slideHeightRef);
      return (
        <StyledSlide key={index} innerRef={slideHeightRef}>
          {React.cloneElement(component)}
        </StyledSlide>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.getSlides()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on the best way forward would be greatly appreciated! Or how to best tackle this problem

Comment: I've definitely had a problem like this with React before. My solution was to make sure that my created Ref was valid. In your forEach callback, you can do a check like if(ref.current){ //execute logic }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resize events likely trigger before your element has rendered. Just add an extra conditional:

```
  handleResize = () => {
    let highestSlide = 0;

    this.refArray.forEach(ref => {
      if (ref.current && highestSlide < ref.current.offsetHeight) {
        highestSlide = ref.current.offsetHeight;
      }
    });
  };
```